# How to clear Clipboard when running program on remote machine?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, selenium-grid

Environment:

Win 7| Selenium-WebDriver|Java|TeamCity CI

Issue: I am testing a textBox that gets the data from clipboard.
When I running my testcase on Local machine, it's working fine. However, if I am running my test case on Node machine (different Win 7 machine via Selenium Grid) then it's getting node machine's Clipboard and pasting node machine's clipboard data.
How can I get Hub machine's clipboard on a Node machine? OR How can I copy text on Node Machine's clipboard?

```
    public static void populateClipboard(String content) {
    Clipboard systemClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(content);
    systemClipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
}
```

Comment: Why would you build a test that passes data using the clipboard? Just pass the data to the test the normal way.

Comment: How can I copy any text on the "node machine's Clipboard", when I am running my testcase via Selenium Grid